# Find the Coordinates of a cell top left ? Working with EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am trying to map a image into a excel spread sheet and i need to find what the coordinates of the current cell are?

My code at the moment loops though each cell till it finds a matching tag in the excel where it knows this is the cell to place the picture.

I have the cell i just have no idea how to obtain the cells top and left properties?

```
foreach (ExcelRangeBase cell in range1)
     {

     }
```

Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int row = cellAddress.Start.Row;
int column = cellAddress.Start.Column;


if (mCellsResult.Count() > 0)
{
var mCells = mCellsResult.First();

//if the cell and the merged cell do not share a common start address then skip this cell as it's already been covered by a previous item
if (mCells.Start.Address != cellAddress.Start.Address)
                                                        continue;

if (mCells.Start.Column != mCells.End.Column)
{
colSpan += mCells.End.Column - mCells.Start.Column;
}

if (mCells.Start.Row != mCells.End.Row)
{
   rowSpan += mCells.End.Row - mCells.Start.Row;
}
}
double height = 0, width = 0;
for (int h = 0; h < rowSpan; h++)
{
height += xlWorkSeet1[k].Row(row + h).Height;
}
for (int w = 0; w < colSpan; w++)
{
 width += xlWorkSeet1[k].Column(column + w).Width;
}

double pointToPixel = 0.75;

height /= pointToPixel;
width /= 0.1423;


picture = xlWorkSeet1[k].Drawings.AddPicture(System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + row.ToString() + column.ToString(), image);
picture.From.Column = column - 1;
picture.From.Row = row - 1;
picture.SetSize((int)width, (int)height);
```

Answer (score 1):

Cell.Top and Cell.Left would be nice, but they doesn't exist in EPPlus.
I was inspired by Pomster and made this function:

```
/// <summary>Get top, left, width and height of a given cell.</summary>
    Rectangle GetCellTopLeftCoordinates(ExcelWorksheet worksheet, ExcelRangeBase cell)
    {
        double top = 0, left = 0, width = 0, height = 0;

        //Get top and left position:
        for (int i = 1; i < cell.Start.Row; i++)
            top += worksheet.Row(i).Height;

        for (int i = 1; i < cell.Start.Column; i++)
            left += worksheet.Column(i).Width;

        //Get width and height:
        if (cell.Merge)  //Then the cell are merged with others:
        {
            foreach (string address in worksheet.MergedCells)  //Loop through all merged cells:
                if (Intersect(worksheet.Cells[address], cell))  //Then we have found the particular, merged range:
                {
                    ExcelRange range = worksheet.SelectedRange[address];

                    for (int i = range.Start.Row; i <= range.End.Row; i++)
                        height += worksheet.Row(i).Height;

                    for (int i = range.Start.Column; i <= range.End.Column; i++)
                        width += worksheet.Column(i).Width;

                    break;
                }
        }
        else //No merges - just get dimensions:
        {
            width = worksheet.Column(cell.Start.Column).Width;
            height = worksheet.Row(cell.Start.Row).Height;
        }

        //Convert point to pixels:
        top /= 0.75;
        left /= 0.1423;
        height /= 0.75;
        width /= 0.1423;
        return new Rectangle((int)left, (int)top, (int)width, (int)height);
    }

    bool Intersect(ExcelRange range, ExcelRangeBase cell)
    {
        foreach (ExcelRangeBase item in range)
            if (item.Address == cell.Address)
                return true;

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: This function works well, however be aware: the Rectangle constructor in GetCellTopLeftCoordinates's final return is used erroneously: the "top" and "left" arguments should be switched.

Answer (score 0):

Try `cell.top` and `cell.left`, they exist in the excel object model.

Answer (score -1):

How to get the upper-left corner of an excel range:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
...
// get upper left corner of range defined by a RangeStr like "B2:D4"
Excel.Range UpperLeftCell = (Excel.Range)wsheet.get_Range(RangeStr).Cells[1,1];
```

where wsheet is a Worksheet object.

Comment: The OP is requesting information specific  to EPPlus. Therefore Interop is not useful.